# Words/phrases to describe the exhaust/lack of something?

Tags: synonyms

Is there any other way of saying the following sentence, specifically the area of text marked in bold without altering its original meaning?

> I've **spent my last dollars** buying useless medicine...

Comment: This sounds like a test question from an exam of some sort.  Otherwise, please give more context & explanation.  You may also find that English Language Learners at http://ell.stackexchange.com/ is more suitable to your needs.

Comment: Thanks! I'm currently developing a video game but my knowledge is quite limited so I can only use simple words and phrases to translate the game content from my main language to English. What I want to achieve exactly is to put emphasis on the lack of money of the character (who speaks this line of dialogue), but I don't know any possible alternatives. Google gives almost no result.

Comment: Is it specific to money or supposed to work with everything?

Comment: Are you looking for idiomatic ways of saying someone has no money?

Comment: @vickyace It'd be great if it also works with something other than money. I just want to make sure the question will be useful for those with similar problems.

Comment: @Spagirl Yes! That'd be great.

Comment: If you want to market it in countries that do not use the dollar, you should avoid any usage of the name of a specific currency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider *[tapped out](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tapped+out)*

> out of money :  broke

The term can also mean

> spent, exhausted: *tapped out after months on the road*

*Merriam-Webster*

Comment: I think this is the perfect word for it. Thanks! (ugh can't upvote the answer though, I don't have 15 reps yet...)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the verb to waste?

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/waste

Comment: I did, but it would be better if it can be said in idiomatic ways (as @Spagirl suggested). :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the UK, you could use *['skint'](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/skint?s=t)*

> adjective, British Slang.
>
> 1 - having no money; penniless.
>
> *www.dictionary.com*

Thus "I am ***skint*** from buying useless medicine."

If you wanted to get *really* idiomatic (and still in the UK) you could used the word *'boracic'* in place of *'skint'*. 'Boracic' is a contraction of the [Cockney Rhyming Slang](http://www.cockneyrhymingslang.co.uk/) term '[Boracic Lint](http://www.cockneyrhymingslang.co.uk/slang/boracic_lint)'

> Boracic Lint is Cockney slang for Skint (broke).
>
> *"Can't come out tonight, I'm Boracic!"*
>
> *www.cockneyrhymingslang.co.uk*

Thus "I am Boracic from buying useless medicines"

Comment: 'Boracic' in this usage is usually spelt 'Brassic' .

Comment: @Spagirl Assuming you are serious (?) I disagree, the word is "Boracic" - 'brassic' is merely the phonetic spelling of the Estuary English pronunciation of the word :)

Comment: Yes I am serious.  'Brassic' is a corruption or contraction of 'Boracic', undoubtedly based on pronunciation. It is also undoubtedly slang, but *in my experience* it is the written form you will find most often for this usage. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/brassic

Comment: Ugh... It is the end of days ;)

Comment: It took me a long time to find out that the 'brassic' I read in novels was connected to the 'skint' that I also read and that there was a more formal spelling.

Comment: I'd prefer a much more formal (I think that's the right word for it) term, but thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Tou [use something up](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/use-sth-up) means to exhaust of strength or useful properties properties or finish or burn up a supply of something.

See another [definition of use up](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/use%20up) from Merriam Webster.

Comment: That's definitely a choice. I'll look it up. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I think [Impoverished](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/impoverished) could work

Def. -> exhaust the strength, vitality, or natural fertility of.

```
  His heart is being impoverished by annual disappointments
```

Comment: *Impoverish* is transitive: you impoverish someone, you don't simply *impoverish*. You could perhaps say "grows weaker/poorer".

Comment: It is both https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#transitive

Comment: Didn't your teacher tell you that Wikipedia and Wikionary are not reliable authorities?